# Can't send ETC from MyEtherWallet using MetaMask wallet

Tags: myetherwallet, ethereum-classic

I'm using Metamask with MEW. I sent 1.14 ETC to the address. I also sent some ETH for gas to the same address as seen below.

[image: Gastracker info]

But when I go to MetaMask Chrome Ext, it only shows ETH. When I go to MEW to send ETC, I see the ETC in the same address, as seen below

[[image: EtcInWallet][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Woi.jpg)

It all goes well on MEW's end, as seen below

[image: Mew info to send ETC]

After I hit the "make transaction" button, MetaMask window pops up as seen below

[image: MetaMask thinks I'm Trying to send ETH]

And it reads "insufficient balance for transaction" because going back to the beginning of the post, Metamask wallet thinks I'm trying to send 1.14 ETH???
I don't know what to do at this point. Any help is desperately needed.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I figured it out. Here's a "how to" in case someone else is in my shoes...
Go to Metamask and enter your password

[image]

Click on the 3 dots. Choose export private key.

[image]

You can click on it and it automatically copies it and/or you can also download the private key for backup purposes.

[image]

Go to Myetherwallet.com and click on send ether and tokens
[image]

Choose Private key and paste the key you copied from MetaMask.

[image]

Unlock your wallet

[image]

Now you should be able to see your balance in the wallet. Since we're trying to send ETC, make sure you have the ETC network selected.

[image]

The rest is the usual procedure to send currencies... I believe the problem is you can't choose the correct network in MetaMask wallet.